# Como incorporar transacción, commit, rollback usando linq entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, transacciones

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
[HttpPost()]
ActionResult ActualizaUbicacion(Ubicacion ubicacion, Persona pers) {
    Using;
    ((void)(db));
    new gvc_dbEntities();
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.Persona.Add(pers)
        db.Ubicacion.Add(ubicacion);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return Json(2);
}
```

> ¿Como incorporo una transacción cuando hay mas de dos objetos
>   guardando?

Resulta que guardo Ubicación y Pesona, pero puede darse el caso de que en persona tenga los valores correctos, y guarde bien, pero en persona puede darse el caso que haya un error al guardar(por decir un ejemplo), produciendose inconsistencia en los datos, ya que en una tabla guardo y en la otra no.

> ¿como se inicializa la transacción, colocando el commit, el rollback
>   en caso de error, o como se hace algo similar que cumpla los mismos
>   objetivos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos maneras en las cuales puedes utilizar "transactions" en Entity Framework. Una es utilizando TransactionScope y la otra es utilizando "database transaction".

Para utilizar "database transaction", aquí un ejemplo:

```
using (dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext())
using (var dbContextTransaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
{
    try
    { 
        var user = new User(){ID = 1, Name = "Nick"};
        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        dbContextTransaction.Commit(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception) 
    { 
        dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); 
    }
}
```

Y aquí otro ejemplo utilizando Entity Framework "TransactionScope":

```
using (TransactionScope tranScope = new TransactionScope())
using (dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext())
{
    try
    {
        var user = new User(){ID = 1, Name = "Nick"};
        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        tranScope.Complete();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

Como puedes ver, es innecesario llamar a algún método de Roll-Back en el caso de usar "TransactionScope". Si no llamas al método "Complete()", la transacción no se envía y de esa manera genera un "RollBack" automáticamente antes de ser liberado de memoria.

Respuesta extraída de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46628700/3613462